# Are line breaks in raw strings platform-dependent?

Tags: string, kotlin, cross-platform, line-breaks, rawstring

Are line breaks in raw strings platform-dependent?

```
val a = "one\ntwo";

val b = """one
two"""

println(a == b)
```

In other words, is the `println` statement above guaranteed to print `true` or not?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any sources specifically stating this. It feels like something that should be in the docs.

There is, however, the intention action in IntelliJ that converts a raw string to an ordinary string. I think it should be safe to assume that this action should not change the meaning of your code (or if it does, that should be filed as a bug). If you try this on a raw string with a newline in it, you can see that it replaces the newline with a `\n` character.

You can see the source of the action [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/intentions/ToOrdinaryStringLiteralIntention.kt), and a test for it that expects it to convert the newline to `\n` [here (before)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/testData/intentions/toOrdinaryStringLiteral/simple.kt) and [here (after)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/testData/intentions/toOrdinaryStringLiteral/simple.kt.after).

---

Edit: [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19842#comment=27-2395091)'s a comment on an issue about raw strings that (as far as I understand) states that a raw string has `\n` line endings in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider it guarantee that `a` and `b` are equal.  The [Spec](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-literals) has this to say about raw string literals:

> Kotlin has two types of string literals: escaped strings that may have escaped characters in them and raw strings that can contain newlines and arbitrary text.

1. The spec doesn't say it's the same
2. The spec makes a differentiation between "newline" and "arbitrary text"
3. And in the link by @zsmb13 to a Kotlin discussion, a Kotlin engineer says the compiler does not preserve the newlines in raw strings (??).

So, if I were writing code to work across platforms, I would be explicit (at least until they are).